# How to create FB likebox with special URL characters

Tags: facebook, facebook-likebox

I'm trying to create a like for box my clients FB page:
https://www.facebook.com/pages/Cateringinventardk-alt-til-dit-storkøkken-og-café

I guess that little ø or é is messing it up, I got this error:

*The `href` parameter must reference a valid Facebook page, but "https://www.facebook.com/pages/Cateringinventardk-alt-til-dit-storkøkken-og-café" is not a valid Facebook page.

Anyone who know how I can prevent that with special url/code?

Thanks in advance!
Jan Joergensen

Answer (score 0):

You could try and specify a **url-encoded value** for the URL. For the URL you supplied this would be something like this:

> https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fpages%2FCateringinventardk-alt-til-dit-stork%C3%B8kken-og-caf%C3%A9

I've always used [this tool](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/), but any other url-encoding tool should do the same job. You might not need to encode the entire URL but rather only the "problematic" characters. For you that's everything after `/pages/`.

```
Cateringinventardk-alt-til-dit-storkøkken-og-café
```

Would become

```
Cateringinventardk-alt-til-dit-stork%C3%B8kken-og-caf%C3%A9
                                    ^----^           ^----^
                                    encoded ø        encoded é
```

Comment: Thanks Lix, but not working. I'm using the Developer tool:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-box-for-pages

Comment: @user3173611 - where exactly are you getting this error? Only after you implement the code you got from facebook?

Comment: Yes. If I insert the url on the developer pages, the preview don not show up. If I fetch the code and insert that on my page, I get the error. If I use a more standard url - no problem :-(

Comment: I feel stupid! I had to append the id after the url: https://www.facebook.com/pages/Cateringinventardk-alt-til-dit-storkøkken-og-café/412517308770577

Comment: @user3173611 - I strongly recommend that you add your own answer to this post and mark it as accepted - that really **is** the correct answer here :)

Answer (score 0):

I had to use the full url, not just the page vanity url